# SSE with ServiceStack not working with netscaler

Tags: servicestack, eventsource

Our application uses ServiceStack and exploits SSE. One of customer's site tries to use the application behind Netscaler, however event-stream connection aborted each time the request is issued from client and SSE does not work. When web server is used directly without Netscaler, SSE works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with netscaler but it sounds like some kind of proxy / middleware in which case any buffering or [HTTP Chunking should be disabled](https://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#notes).

It looks like this document shows how to [prevent HTTP chunking in Citrix netscaler](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX121948).