# Citrix Netscaler block ServiceStack Server Events

Tags: servicestack, citrix, eventsource, netscaler

I'm using Service Stack Server Event to push notification to the clients, but one customer need to host Server Stack apphost behind a Citrix Netscaler.  In this scenario all connection seems to be aborted by the cliet and sse does not work.

In the post [SSE with ServiceStack not working with netscaler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504705/sse-with-servicestack-not-working-with-netscaler/58076173#58076173) mythz suggest to setup citrix in order to prevent the backend Server from Sending Chunked Responses.

Does anyone know if it works?

Note that if I point directly to the apphost instead of the netloader sse works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution that you linked, disable chunks https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX121948 or, expanding on mythz, you can use either SSL_BRIDGE or just TCP vserver and service types, so that the netscaler does not perform HTTP inspection.

Answer (score 0):

The only other thing I'd add to the linked answer that could help is using SSL which would prevent deep packet inspection and potentially any interference by any middleware.

Comment: SSL will be used soon.  I immagine you didn't get any feedback from that user if your suggestion worked out... right?

Comment: @EnricoGobbo nope, have not received any feedback.